Redirecting traffic from one usb port to another?
Is it possible to use a linux machine as some sort of usb passthrough?
In the sense that the linux machine would act as host on one port and gadget on the other.
What I am trying to achieve is to merely observe traffic on the host port and report it to gadget port.
I'm not trying spoof or fake the usb port to act like something it's not (ideally it would simply mirror the hardware information from whatever is plugged to the host end, to the gadget end).
Ultimate goal is to alter/add/remove the data passing through the machine.
Any help is appreciated

If a computer can do that function (ie. USB hardware/chips will have limits on what they can allow (esp. in regards masking what they are), which is device/chipset specific), you'll be able to do it on the machine on any OS once programmed to do it. This isn't a Linux programming site however, but a Ubuntu Q&A support site, with Linux support handled at SE Unix & Linux   (see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

@guiverc I understand, I will go ask there, thank you
